# Passing data from autocomplete to dynamic Hidden ID

Tags: jquery, hidden, html-input

So I have this

```
    $('input[name^="numEmp"]').autocomplete({source: Empleados,select: function(event, ui){
    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    $('#nomDetEmp').val(ui.item.value);     
    return false;
    }
    });
```

I create dynamic inputs like this

```
   $(".Nuevo").on("click", function() {

   $(".readdireccion:first").clone().insertAfter(".readdireccion:last").find('input[name^="numEmp"],input[name^="servicioNom"],input[name^="numCta"],input[name^="cantidad"],').val("");

   $('input[name^="numEmp"]').autocomplete({source: Empleados,select: function(event, ui){

   $(this).val(ui.item.label);
   return false;
```

and the html is like this

```
<div class="readdireccion">
<div class="input_quitapon">

<a class="Eliminar">Erase</a>

        <div class="input_element">
            <div class="input_label">Numero Empleado</div>
            <div class="input_value">
                <input type="text" name="numEmp[]" class="emp" maxlength="10" size="12" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="nomDetEmp[]" id="nomDetEmp" class="emp" maxlength="10" size="12" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now my question is I assign the fields numEmp[] and they have no ID because it is just for the user view, but the hidden ones store the info that gets sent to the database. How can I assign them? The problem I have with the codes is that it only saves to the first hidden field and not the new ones.

Comment: Id should be unoque, the id `nomDetEmp` can't be more than one in the page.

Comment: Yeah I know that but I was all out of ideas this is where I stopped and decided to ask for help